# Access values from json in react

Tags: json, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to access variables from json in react component.

This is JSON I am getting:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Hello",
    "text": "Hello, this is my first article...",
    "picture": "pic",
    "comments": [],
    "user": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Anonim",
        "password": "123456"
    }
}
```

The attached user is person who created the post.
The attached comments is list of comments related to this post.
In routing I am doing the following:

```
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/' exact component={PostsPage} />
      <Route path='/:id' exact component={PostProfilePage} />
    </Switch>
```

In react class component

```
class PostProfile extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    // Pass props to the parent component
    super(props);
    // Set initial state
    this.state = {
      // State needed
      post: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchPost();
  }

  fetchPost() {
    const {match} = this.props
    const id = match.params.id
    console.log(id)
    fetch('/'+id)
    .then(res => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        post: data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <li> {this.state.post.title} </li>
      <li> {this.state.post.text} </li>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(PostProfile)
```

**does not work**

```
 <li> {this.state.post.user.name} </li>
  <li> {this.state.post.comments...} </li>
```

Why I cannot access user and comments?
And is it possible to get user and comments in different components? (not calling the fetch method again and again)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does `this.state.post` yield anything?

Comment: yes, the same as JSON

Comment: don't show any error on console? on the first render?

Comment: I put `console.log(this.state.post.user.name) ` and `console.log(this.state.post.user)` in render. it shows `this.state.post.user` but not the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post at first time has no data, so you need something like:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // Pass props to the parent component
    super(props);
    // Set initial state
    this.state = {
      // State needed
      post: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchPost();
  }

  fetchPost() {

    fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/1')
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          post: data
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const show = this.state.post.length === 0 ? 
      <h1> ...loading </h1> 
      : <h1> {this.state.post.birth_year} </h1> 
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> { show } </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I also can return different parts separately!

Comment: I am really sorry, but I need to ask one thing more. Is it possible to get another condition with the same logic inside const condition. because now I have the same problem when load array of comments. I tried, but the syntax is wrong

Comment: Alright, put the logic inside a function that returns loading... Or anything. You can do with a lot of possible.

Comment: Here https://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2017/07/react-extracting-logic/ a example how and where put your logic